# calculate the space complexity of a C program

Tags: c, gcc, cygwin

I want to calculate the space complexity ~ memory usages of a C program on Windows.
I want to do this all with out viewing the Task Manager.
I found that [link](http://ideone.com/hBOux) calculates the space for the code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main(void) { 
  int x; 
  for(; scanf("%d",&x) > 0 && x != 42; printf("%d\n", x)); 
  return 0; 
}
```

to be **1724 kB**

1. How is te being calculated?
2. How can I implement any system which calculates such a space complexity measure for a piece of code?

Your answer will be welcomed.

Comment: What is *space complexity*?  Is it related to memory usage?

Comment: Space requirements (i.e. memory usage) can be measured at run-time (e.g. with `/proc/1234/maps` for process 1234 on Linux). Space complexity is an entire different subject http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_theory and is *very hard* to compute precisely in the most general case (probably untractable or undecidable, in the general or pathological case).

Comment: well, the stupidest answer to your question (and the one I use) is simply to check the process's memory usage in Task Manager (or any other process monitor), if by _space complexity_ you are referring to memory usage.

Comment: @wallyk actually i want to calculate the memory taken by a C program to run. i.e. if it use `int a` then basically is used **4 bytes** and so on.
Now I want to calculate such memory taken by whole program.

Comment: How would you deal with `malloc`-ated heap data, whose size depends upon the input???

Answer (score 4):

Ankit, from your reply to wallyk it is clear that there is some confusion here. The term space complexity here could mean many different things, ranging from the smaller size of the code executable; to the amount of resources allocated to a process and how the quantity of those resources change during execution.

The 1724 could be calculated in many different ways depending upon what it represents. Does it represent everything in the resulting executable, or only the "code" text? Does it matter that executable sizes will be different on different platforms? And this only concerns static information. Dynamic information (information about the programs performance at runtime) is another can of worms.

In that case, what you have to realize is that the resources allocated to a process may not exactly match the bare minimum needed by the process. If you are asking for a program that looks for the minimum memory size that needs to be allocated to a process you get into very murky ground: are you talking about the physical memory required, or the virtual memory from the point of view of the process? For example, if we are running two instances of the same process, then two processes can share the read-only (e.g. code memory) and therefore one of the instances will not need to have that calculated for it. Asking the operating system for such calculations is problematic since it will need to know very precisely what you are asking for, while having a program which calculates runtime memory use by looking at the code text and ignoring the platform is also problematic.

Calculating this minimum is extremely non-trivial, though it may have already been accomplished by someone. Either way you will need to search for it using terms more concrete and less confusing than "space complexity", which is something more applicable to a pen and paper algorithm.